# Formula for Populating Cells in Task Scheduler (Excel 2013)

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to create a task scheduler in excel. I'll have a start month and an end month, but I'd like to fill in the periods in between. For instance, right now my table looks like this:

```
+--------+-------+-----+-------+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
| Task   | Jan   | Feb | Mar   | Apr | May | Jun | Jul | Aug |
+--------+-------+-----+-------+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
| Task A | Start |     |       |     | End |     |     |     |
+--------+-------+-----+-------+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
| Task B |       |     | Start | End |     |     |     |     |
+--------+-------+-----+-------+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
| Task C | Start |     |       |     |     | End |     |     |
+--------+-------+-----+-------+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
```

For "Task A", I'd like to have the cells in between Jan - May have some text like "Work" or something similar.

So the final table would like this:

```
+--------+-------+------+-------+------+------+-----+-----+-----+
| Task   | Jan   | Feb  | Mar   | Apr  | May  | Jun | Jul | Aug |
+--------+-------+------+-------+------+------+-----+-----+-----+
| Task A | Start | Work | Work  | Work | End  |     |     |     |
+--------+-------+------+-------+------+------+-----+-----+-----+
| Task B |       |      | Start | End  |      |     |     |     |
+--------+-------+------+-------+------+------+-----+-----+-----+
| Task C | Start | Work | Work  | Work | Work | End |     |     |
+--------+-------+------+-------+------+------+-----+-----+-----+
```

This is a dynamically changing table, so hard-coding the text in there isn't an option.

Update:

Because this table is dynamic, this table is linked to a table on another tab. It pulls the data with a simple formula "=Sheet1!B2" dragged across the table.

Answer (score 2):

This is assuming that your data starts on cell A1.  You will need to change the for loops for the row and column counter if it does not.

```
Sub fillTask()
Dim intRow As Integer, intStartFlg As Integer
Dim mySht As Worksheet

Set mySht = Sheets("Sheet1")
intStartFlg = 0

'get last row
intRow = mySht.Cells(mySht.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

'loop through each task
For i = 2 To intRow
    'Clear previous loop
    For j = 2 To 13
        If mySht.Cells(i, j) <> "Start" Or mySht.Cells(i, j) <> "End" Then mySht.Cells(i, j).ClearContents
    Next j

    'loop through each month
    For j = 2 To 13
        If mySht.Cells(i, j) = "end" Then Exit For
        If intStartFlg = 1 Then mySht.Cells(i, j) = "Work"
        If mySht.Cells(i, j) = "Start" Then intStartFlg = 1
    Next j
    intStartFlg = 0
Next i
```

End Sub

Comment: This is almost perfect! Hopefully a quick change, in edit that I made to my original post, can we edit your code so that it first loops through the linked formula to grab the start and end dates ("=Sheet1!B2"), and then runs your original code? I'm not sure how to incorporate that in right now with my limited VBA skills

Comment: I am not sure what you mean?  So does your table always start on cell A1 but the columns are dynamic? Meaning that instead of showing Jan - Dec it could be Jan-Dec of 2019 and then Jan - Dec 2020?

Comment: The header columns (Jan-Dec) are hardcoded and don't change but the tasks themselves do (it's linked via slicer), basically everything from A2-M2 is dynamic. Sometimes there will be 5 tasks, sometimes 100, and the date ranges will change respectively.Right now, your code hard codes "work" into a cell, so if the slicer changes, the "Work" field will stay hard coded in the cell regardless. I'd like to incorporate that formula "=Sheet1!B2" to check if there is start/end date present first and if there is, run your code, otherwise just leave it linked as "=Sheet1!B2".Sorry I'm makin this confusing

Comment: All you would need to do is just call this query in the worksheet change event for that sheet: 

`Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Call filltask
End Sub`

Comment: I also updated the code to first clear out anything that says work before exectuing

Comment: Receiving a "Next without For" error. Really appreciate your help on this!!!!!!!!

Comment: My bad.  I was trying to separate fixes and forgot to clear out the old one.  Updated version should work.